# How do I measure loudness level of a device in environment?

Tags: acoustics, measurements

I want to measure the individual loudness level of a device in environment.

Fistly, I measure loudness level when the device is ON (95.5dB)
Then I measure loudness level when the device is OFF (48.5dB)

The engineer said that the device loudness level is 95.5-48.5=47dB

But I think it must be ~95.5 because it still depending in many factor such as: environment sound frequency and device sound frequency...

Comment: What is your definition of "loudness level"?

Comment: You are correct, but not for the reasons you mention. A proper dB calculator can be found here https://noisemeters.com/apps/db-calculator.asp

Comment: @ACuriousMind: sorry for the confuse. I mean "loudness level" is simple loudness measuring by dB

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams you rock man!!!!

Comment: @sonpython Oh boy, you made me blush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the math:  If $\beta$ is the level in dB and I is the intensity (power/area) in watts per square meter, $$\beta=10\log\left(\frac{I}{10^{-12}}\right).$$
Inverting that we get that $$I=10^{-12}\cdot 10^{\beta/10}.$$
$$\beta = 95.5\ \mathrm{dB} \to I = 3.548\times 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{W/m}^2$$
$$\beta = 48.5\ \mathrm{dB} \to I = 7.079\times 10^{-8}\ \mathrm{W/m}^2$$

A reasonable assumption for non-coherent sound sources is that the intensities add, so subtracting the background intensity be get the device intensity is 
$$I = 3.548\times 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{W/m}^2$$ which has a level of $95.5$ dB

Answer (score 0):

Just talk with supporter from noisemetters, he explained:

> Mike:
>
> Hi Michael
>
> Mike:
>
> The loudness will be 95.5
>
> Michael Phan:
>
> can you confirm that the loudness of the device is 95.5
>
> Mike:
>
> Yes, you can't mathematically subtract decibel levels as the decibel
>   scale is logarithmic.
>
> Michael Phan:
>
> thank you
>
> Mike:
>
> Any level that is 12dB or more above the background noise level will
>   not be influenced by the background level
>
> Mike:
>
> Is there anything else I can help you with
>
> Michael Phan:
>
> thank you Mike
>
> Michael Phan:
>
> have a nice day
>
> Mike:
>
> You too.